# Swapping axes for a 2-predictor GAM in r

Tags: r, plot, contour, gam, mgcv

I apologize for such a simple question, but have not been able to find the answer yet perusing the site.  I am trying to plot a series of GAM models of invertebrate capture data in R. One of the predictors is always a smoothed term for the day of year number (DOY).  This should always occupy the space of the x-axis.  The y-axis should be either a linear or smoothed weather variable predictor.  With the vis.gam() function, I can produce a surface contour plot with a color gradient representing predicted values of the response for any x-y pair.  When the second predictor is nonlinear, as in:

```
totbest=gam(Totallog10pl1~s(DOY)+s(SRVarDetrendDerived),data=poolREplotGAM)
```

then the figure looks as it should (apologies for not being able to post images, but here is the plotting command):

```
vis.gam(totbest, type="response",plot.type="contour",n.grid=50)
```

But when the predictor is linear:

```
totbest1=gam(Totallog10pl1~s(DOY)+SRVarDetrendDerived,data=poolREplotGAM)
```

the axes switch:

```
vis.gam(totbest1, type="response",plot.type="contour",n.grid=50)
```

If you have a means of returning the time-related variable to the x-axis, that would be very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be due to the order in which the `var.summary` element of the gam object is returned.  Try `totbest$var.summary` vs `totbest1$var.summary`.

A "fix" would be to do this:

```
totbest1$var.summary <- totbest1$var.summary[2:1]
vis.gam(totbest1, type="response",plot.type="contour",n.grid=50)
```

Caveat: I haven't read enough about the gam object to understand whether the reverse order of `var.summary` is by design.

hope this helps!  Rich.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I hate to come crawling back like this, but I introduced a wrinkle into my model that has made reorienting my figures as above impossible, as far as I can see.  I've been tweaking it and can't figure this out.  I have included a factor/smooth interaction, as in: totbest=gam(Totallog10pl1~s(SRVarDetrendDerived)+s(DOY,by=Plot),na.action=na.omit,data=poolFACTORplotGAM). Reordering the smooths in the code places the SRVar and DOY on the axes, instead of DOY and Plot, but it now always sets DOY on the Y axis. @RichAtMango, or anyone else, might you have a suggestion? Thanks again for any help!